# How to catch "closing" click event?

Tags: javascript, events, click, onclick, popupmenu

Here’s an example. This is Google menu.

[image]

When you click on the gear-wheel (red cross) the menu appears. When you click anywhere beyond opened menu (green cross) the menu disappear. The question is how to catch that second closing event (green cross).

It’s simple to open the menu.

```
var x = document.getElementById("star");          // this is id of the gear-wheel;
var y = document.getElementById("hiddenMenu");    // this is id of the menu with display = none;
x.onclick = function() {
    y.style.display = "block";
}
```

But how to make it closed? I tried this way using "body" tag:

```
var bar = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
bar.onclick = function() {
    if (y.style.display == "block") {
       y.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

But the menu is closed immediately after it has been opened. First it becomes “block” as “star” is clicked. But immediately after this becomes “none” as body is also clicked. How to solve it? Is it really necessary to write code for "body" for catching right target event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
star.addEventListener("click", closeIfOpen);
document.addEventListener("click", closeIfClickOutsideMenu);
```

Comment: Yes, such solution looks nice, but "blur" cannot be applyed to div elements just that easy, unfurtunatly

Comment: @Green why not? Ugh blur doesn't work on divs. Ok you'll need something else. Looks like you need a click handler and a check whether the click is within the div

Answer (score 1):

This is due to bubbling/event propagation.  The listener on `#star` fires first, then the event bubbles up to the body and it fires there.

You need to cancel event propagation.  Unfortunately this is not particularly easy using inline handlers without a library.

```
var x = document.getElementById("star");          // this is id of the gear-wheel;
var y = document.getElementById("hiddenMenu");    // this is id of the menu with display = none;
x.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }else{
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    y.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: this is not particularly easy using inline handlers without a library. What kind of library do you mean? jQuery?